# RecyclerView Fragment error at inflating

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to display data from a JSONObject in a RecyclerView in a Fragment, but I get the error

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35:
>   Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment
>
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35:
>   Error inflating class fragment
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object reference

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
@Override
public void onListFragmentInteraction(int position) {
    mToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    mToast.show();
}

void createFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mDiscoverFragment = new DiscoverFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.discover_fragment, mDiscoverFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
...
```

**Fragment.java**

```
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDiscoverList = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.discover_list);
    LinearLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mDiscoverList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mDiscoverList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    try {
        mAdapter = new DiscoverAdapter(new DiscoverContent().getItems(), mListener);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mDiscoverList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover_list, container, false);
    return view;
}
...
```

Can someone tell me what causes the problem?

Comment: share your layout xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the layout and the view before it's "ready".

Move the following lines to the `onCreateView()` method:

```
 mDiscoverList = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.discover_list);
    LinearLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mDiscoverList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mDiscoverList.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

The final results should look somthing like that:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover_list, container, false);

    mDiscoverList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.discover_list);
    LinearLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = newLinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mDiscoverList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mDiscoverList.setHasFixedSize(true); 

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I just did, but the problem is still the same. :/

Comment: Try replacing getView() method with the parameter view. See my final result example.

Comment: Yes, I did that too. I also updated the post, with some extra error messages I got

Comment: Yes. New error message: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout. There is that JSONException check in onCreate, which seem to cause the problem. The code inside the try does not run.

Comment: Did you move the code related to the adapter into the onCreateView() method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148162/discussion-between-balazs-orban-and-mrsegev).